# Highcharts custom colours

Tags: highcharts

```js
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'emmisions2015',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: '60%'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                ['Direct Emissions', 5],
                ['Purchased Electricity', 15],
                ['Transport', 40]
                ]}]
    },
    // using 
                                     
    function(chart) { // on complete
        
        var xpos = '50%';
        var ypos = '53%';
        var circleradius = 102;
    
    // Render the circle
    chart.renderer.circle(xpos, ypos, circleradius).attr({
        fill: '#fff',
    }).add();

    // Render the text 
    chart.renderer.text('2015', 370, 225).css({
            width: circleradius*2,
            color: '#87868a',
            fontSize: '23px',
            textAlign: 'center'
      }).attr({
            // why doesn't zIndex get the text in front of the chart?
            zIndex: 999
        }).add();
    });
});
```

Hello! we are trying to these graphs with the exact same colours:
[image]

We have this code that generates de graphs but it doesn't take the custom colours we want. In other words we try to add our custom colour codes but it doesn't seem to take them. TIA for your help/ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot finally we managed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply prepend your set of colors or override the existing colors by just passing the color palette as an array.

Here is the default colors of Highcharts

```
colors: ['#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce','#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a']
```

From image i can say these are the colors you want

```
'#51b5ce', '#89c733', '#54a329'
```

now simply add this to the chart

```
colors: ['#51b5ce', '#89c733', '#54a329','#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce', '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a'],
```

This will work for you. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ttf5nor0/) is a jsfiddle for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

Colors could be set for chart - [for all series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors).

This could be overridden for each series by setting colors [for a series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.colors) when using [color by point](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.colorByPoint). For `pie` type series `colorByPoint` is set to true by default.

```js
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'emmisions2015',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: '60%'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            colors: ['#f0f','#ff0','#0ff'],
            data: [
                ['Direct Emissions', 5],
                ['Purchased Electricity', 15],
                ['Transport', 40]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="emmisions2015"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! there are many ways of achieving this. We finally managed!